# How to rotate all the object in vertical orientation?

Tags: image, image-processing, computer-vision, rotation, image-rotation

The object in the image are in different orientation. I want to change all object orientation in vertical. The code is shown below. The code doesn't all object orientation to vertical. [[Image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkkkO.jpg)

```
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Sam.jpg')
Gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# create a binary  image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(Gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# find the contours from the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
[-2:]
           
for i in range(len(contours)):            
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])             
    angle=rect[2]
    print('rect',rect)
    print('ANgle:',angle)
    
  
    if angle>0:
        rangle =  90-angle
        print('rangle:',rangle)
    else:
        rangle =angle
        print('rangle:',rangle)
    rotate_img=  ndimage.rotate(cimg, rangle,reshape=True)
    print('rotate_img shape:',rotate_img.shape)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.title('rotate_img')
    plt.imshow(rotate_img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: How about thresholding the image and using [skimage.label](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.label) to find each component in the image. next, find the center of mass of each component and a bounding box around it. find the angle the object in the ROI and rotate the object so that it will be verticle. finally paste the rotated ROI on either the old image or a new image such that the center of mass of the rotated object will be at the center of mass of the original object.

Comment: @yannziselman Thank you for your suggestion. Yes, I want to find angle of rotation such that objects in the image always in vertical.

Comment: you can find the angle by finding the correlation between the x indices of the pixels belonging to the object and their y indices

Comment: @yannziselman could you please describe in more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To rotate objects in the vertical orientation, we first need to find the orientation of a object. OpenCV provides  a function cv2.minAreaRect() to find minimum area rectangle's center,(height, width)and angle of rotation. Height must be larger than width to be in the vertical orientation. The angle of rotation only is not enough for the vertical orientation. The angle of rotation reiterating -0 to -90 because of following reason. More detail here: [the ai learner](https://theailearner.com/tag/cv2-minarearect/) and [namkeenman](https://namkeenman.wordpress.com/2015/12/18/open-cv-determine-angle-of-rotatedrect-minarearect/)

- The lowest point in a rectangle is 0th vertex, and 1st, 2nd, 3rd
  vertices follow clockwise.
- Height is distance between 0th & 1st  (or 2nd & 3rd) vertices.
- Width is distance between 1st  & 2nd (or 0th & 3rd) vertices.
- The angle of rotation is angle between the line (joining the starting and
  endpoint) and the horizontal.

```
image = cv2.imread(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Sam.jpg')
Gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
# Create a binary threshold image
_, binary = cv2.threshold(Gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
# Find the contours from the binary image
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) 
[-2:]
           
for i in range(len(contours)):
    rect = cv2.minAreaRect(contours[i])              
    angle=rect[2]
    rwidth,rheight=rect[2]
    if rheight>rwidth :
        rangle =  angle
        print('rangle:',rangle)
    else:
        rangle =90-abs(angle)
        print('rangle:',rangle)
    rotate_img=  ndimage.rotate(cimg, rangle,reshape=True)
    print('rotate_img shape:',rotate_img.shape)
    plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    plt.title('rotate_img')
    plt.imshow(rotate_img, cmap='gray')
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation for your answer to make it easier for others to understand how you solved the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Thanks yuki and Commmunity , for bringing this to my attention. I have made changes to the answer with details.